# TypeError: __class__ must be set to a class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-2.x

**Python version: 2.7.8**

### Click here to view: [Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USp23.jpg)

---

**--Error:--**

> TypeError: __class__ must be set to a class.

This error is occurring on line 7/line 9 (depending on the version passed) in Web.py ***self.__class__ = Gui_A***.

---

**-->Object created is of Web.py<--**

---

***other_dir***

```
class BaseParent():
    def test(self):
        pass
```

***Dir/__init**.py__*

```
from other_dir import BaseParent

class Base(BaseParent):
    def login(self):
        pass
```

***Dir/dir1/gui_a.py***

```
from Dir import Base

class Gui_A(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Gui_A, self).__init__()
```

***Dir/dir1/gui_b.py***

```
from Dir import Base

class Gui_B(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Gui_B, self).__init__()
```

***Dir/dir2/Web.py***

```
from Dir.dir1.gui_a import Gui_A
from Dir.dir1.gui_b import Gui_B

class Web():
    def __init__(self, version):
        if version == 'gen1':
            self.__class__ = Gui_A
        elif version == 'gen2':
            self.__class__ = Gui_B


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ob = Web("gen1")
```

---

Why is the error trying to indicate that Gui_A is not a class, because of which assignment cannot happen?

Comment: Works for me (python 2.7.10).

Comment: Please post a proper MCVE (and the Python version) - we're not going to recreate all your directory structure just to test this.

Comment: The directory structure was provided so that you get a clear picture of the code structure not for recreating the directory at your end. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

This exception can happen in Python 2 if you mix old-style (classic) and new-style classes.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     # New style class (inherits from object)
...     pass
... 
>>> class B:
...    # Classic class - does not inherit from object
...    # or any other new-style class
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.__class__ = A
... 
>>> B()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: __class__ must be set to a class
```

Old- and new-style classes are actually different types:

```
>>> type(A)
<type 'type'>
>>> type(B)
<type 'classobj'>
```

so you can't substitute one for the other.  New-style classes were introduced in Python 2.2; any modern Python 2 code should use them exclusively unless inheriting from an old-style class (I think there might still be some in the standard library).

In Python 3 old style classes have been eliminated.  Consequently in Python 3 classes may be declared like old-style classes; this declaration would produce an old-style class in Python 2, but a new-style class in Python 3:

```
class A:
    pass
```

If you are creating Python 2 code from Python 3 examples it's important to be aware of this difference.